# How to create parametric variable in class decleration

Tags: string, variables

I hope the subject of this question if correct.

in `timeOUT` constructor, 3 more instances of other class are defined:
`endTimeOUT_inFlash(key1)`,
`inCodeTimeOUT_inFlash(key2)`, 
`updatedTimeOUT_inFlash(key3)`.

```
// ~~~~~~~~~~~ TimeOut Class ~~~~~~~~~~~~
timeOUT::timeOUT(char *sw_num, int def_val,char *key1, char *key2, char *key3)
        : endTimeOUT_inFlash (key1), inCodeTimeOUT_inFlash(key2), updatedTimeOUT_inFlash(key3)
```

I'm looking for a way that `key1` to `key3` will be predefined keys, and `sw_num` will serve as a prefix to those keys.

For example :

```
#define key1 "endTO" 
#define key2 "inCodeTO"
#define key3 "updatedTO"
```

and using `sw_num`'s value will be concatenate as: `SW0_endTO`( for `key1` and so on . `sw_num=SW0` ofcourse).

This way contructor will be :

```
// ~~~~~~~~~~~ TimeOut Class ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    timeOUT::timeOUT(char *sw_num, int def_val)
            : endTimeOUT_inFlash (key1), inCodeTimeOUT_inFlash(key2), updatedTimeOUT_inFlash(key3)
```

Comment: Why do you need this? Anyway you can use sw_num as String and make those concatenations like  sw_num + '_' + key1 ... (that's ugly solution). Or you can have two parameters in constructors and build the string inside of class. Or you can create child classes for each key...  But with knowing context, it might be something completely different

Comment: @KIIV as far as I understand ( tried ), nothing can come before constructor to do such "concatenate"

Comment: @Guy.D, read KIIV's comment again and slow

Comment: This smacks of an [X-Y Problem](http://xyproblem.info). You should more clearly define what you want to achieve, and forget how you *think* you want to achieve it.